# How to create maven modulized project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

I want to create maven multi module project, but it should not like normal module project. My requirement is divide web project in to many parts and some module contents common pages, when building project it need to create many web war files.

Is there any maven plugin for this kind of requirement?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit more in detail? you would like to separate contents pages (JSF, jsp's whatever) in different modules? What's the idea/requirement behind that?

Comment: Is some thing like this. I have three module projects(common, admin and user). When building both admin and user project should add common project content(JSP and Images) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many war files you need to create, you can use [overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) to merge in common pages. This would work if it's ok to have one module per war.

Otherwise, I suggest using different [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to create each different war. Then you would run the build once per war.